# ROBOTC - Unsure about > notation

Tags: c

I am using ROBOTC to program my robot, and I was using some code built by someone else. In a function, I see the line:

```
int leftDir = (left>0)*2-1;
```

`leftDir` is initialized to an integer, so what does the `>` do? I am under the impression that is is a binary shift, but I'm not sure. Can someone explain this?
Thanks.

Comment: Naw. That's the "greater-than" operator. (I'm pretty sure you used that in math formulae, didn't you.)

Comment: but then how is `leftDir` initialized to an integer?

Comment: Without any problems. What's your concern?

Comment: Oh wait. Does it evaluate that binary that is returned as either 1 or 0?

Comment: Operators with boolean results indeed yield `int` (since there's no *real* Boolean type in C, not even `_Bool` is one). 1 is true, 0 is false.

Comment: @H2CO3 This is off the subject, but `_Bool` is a Boolean type in my opinion. Perhaps we don't agree in this case. What constitutes a Boolean type? A type that is capable of storing a maximum of two possible states? That is `_Bool`. If a value X compares equal to 0, the value converted to `_Bool` is 0. Otherwise it is 1 when converted to `_Bool`. What else do you want from the type?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Indeed, you're right. I was mislead (I knew C++'s `bool` behaved like this, but apparently -- and fortunately -- `_Bool` is also doing the right thing). Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Jeeter So apparently I was wrong about the nonexistence of a true Boolean type, but that doesn't change the fact that comparisons yield `int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `>` is the `greater than` operator. In C result of comparison is either `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`. In other words the code above is logically equivalent to (but more compact):

```
int leftDir;

if (left > 0) {
    leftDir = 1;
} else {
    leftDir = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, but i believe he intended it as a bit shifting operator. This would make sense because he went on to multiply the value by a number, implying that he isn't treating it as a boolean. He was incorrect, though, about the roobtc bit shifting notation. If you want to bit shift a number in robotc, use the following syntax:

```
int foo = 0b00001111 >> 2; //bit shifts the bianary number 00001111 over by two bits, so foo will be set to the result 00000011
```